# Axios connecting me to wrong port

Tags: node.js, axios

I am using axios as an HTTP client. When I try to POST on my local server I get this error message:

```
    { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
  config:{......................
       .............................
       .........}
```

I don't know what is wrong in my node js app. I am posting data to port 80(instead of to localhost' port) Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't know what system you're running this on but have checked the port is open by seeing if you can connect with anything else i.e. web browser, telnet..?

Comment: Please share the code where you use Axios to post to the server. You're trying to post to port 80 on localhost

Comment: Are you sure your server is running on port 80? Why do you think Axios is connecting to the wrong port? You say you are posting to port 80, and the error message clearly shows that Axis does try to connect on that port?